# Migration não reconhece o Context

Tags: asp.net-core, ddd, code-first

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando arquitetura DDD. Em minha camada de Infra, tenho os meus modelos de dados, todos baseados em *Code First*. Estou utilizando o *SQL* como banco de dados. Já instalei tudo que foi necessário.

Acontece que quando tento aplicar o *Migration* obtenho o erro:

```html
PM> Add-Migration -MuoContext Initial
Add-Migration : Não é possível localizar um parâmetro que coincida com o nome de parâmetro 'MuoContext'.
No linha:1 caractere:15
+ Add-Migration -MuoContext Initial
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Add-Migration
```

O parâmetro **MuoContext** é o nome de minha classe, como pode ser visto abaixo:

```html
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Muo.Domain.Areas.BI.Entities;
using Muo.Domain.Areas.Commons.Entities;
using Muo.Infrastructure.Data.Mappings.Areas.BI;
using Muo.Infrastructure.Data.Mappings.Areas.Commons;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Muo.Infrastructure.Data.Context
{
    public class MuoContext : DbContext
    {
        #region DbSets
        //DbSets - ../Domain/Areas/Commons/Entities
        public DbSet<CnaeActivity> CnaeActivities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CompanyAddress> CompanyAddresses { get; set; }

        //DbSets - ../Domain/Areas/BI/Entities
        public DbSet<ChartOfAccountStandardDfp> ChartOfAccountStandardDfps { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region Configurations

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Mappings/Areas/BI
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ChartOfAccountStandardDfpMap());

            //Mappings/Areas/Commons
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CompanyMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CompanyAddressMap());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CnaeActivityMap());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }
```

Meu aquivo **appsettings.json** está assim:

```html
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=MuoDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Não entendo e não consigo encontrar uma solução.

Comment: Rode Enable-Migrations

Comment: Obrigado @NetinhoSantos, mas o Enable-Migrations está obsoleto no EFCore. O correto é o *Add-Migration* mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que vc está confundindo com o parâmetro.

O correto seria:

```
Add-Migration --context MuoContext Initial
```

ou

```
Add-Migration -c MuoContext Initial
```

Porém se sua aplicação só tem 1 contexto e o projeto que vc irá gerar o Migration for o mesmo do context então você nem precisa informar:

```
Add-Migration Initial
```